# Parsing html code from website and displaying it on java element

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup

I am trying to parse html code from website to display on java element for a program I am working on.

Here is the image that shows what I am trying to parse:
[image]

I have been looking at **jsoup library** to parse html from **arso.si**.

Any advice how to parse that specific part of code and what element to use to display it on my program.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Have a go yourself first and people would be more willing to help

Comment: I can get html code from that element in Document format parsed but how to display it what element should I use in netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding you are trying to take some part of a website and display it as it is (visually) on your application.

You can use Selenium for that (http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

You can use the PhantomJSDriver to visit the site, then call the `getScreenshotAs` function (more info and example can be found here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you have any advice how to crop image once I take it. Does selenium have a function for that? Thanks again!

Comment: WebDriver also has a function that returns the position and size of an element (in pixels). You can use it to crop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use `jsoup` to parse `html`

```
public static void parseTitleData(String response){

        if (response!=null&&!"".equals(response)) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
            //css selector
            Elements linksElements = doc.select("div[class=article_list mtop10]>ul>li>a");

            for (Element ele:linksElements) {
                String href = ele.attr("href");
                String title = ele.text();
                News news =new News();
                news.setPath(href);
                news.setTitle(title);
            }
        }
    }
```